# Save excel file to disk after binding from repeater

Tags: c#, excel, vb.net, repeater

I'm creating an excel file from a repeater control and allowing the user to save the file. After generating the excel file how can I save this to disk. I want to send this as an attachment inside of an email

```
Dim output As String = WebUI.RenderControl(plcList)
Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=report_dd_rejection.xlxs")
Response.Write(output)
Response.End()
```

Any help with this would be appreciated.

Thanks

Chris

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood your question.

But if already have the Excel data being sent to the user browser, you just need to write the data to disk

```
Dim filePhysicalFolder = Environment.CurrentDirectory()
Dim output As String = WebUI.RenderControl(plcList)

Using outputFile As New StreamWriter(Path.Combine(filePhysicalFolder, "report_dd_rejection.xlxs"))
    outputFile.Write(output)
End Using

Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=report_dd_rejection.xlxs")
Response.Write(output)
Response.End()
```